# stacking geom_ribbon

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use geom_ribbon to mimic the behavior of geom_area
but i am not successful. would you have any hint on why the following does not work ?
I used Hadley's statement from [ggplot2 geom_area web pages](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_area.html) : 
"An area plot is a special case of geom_ribbon, where the minimum of the range is fixed to 0, and the position adjustment defaults to position_stacked."

```
test <- expand.grid(Param = LETTERS[1:3], x = 1:5)
test$y <- test$x

# Ok
p <- ggplot(test)
p <- p + geom_area(aes(x = x, y = y, group = Param, fill = Param), alpha = 0.3)
p

# not ok - initial idea
p <- ggplot(test)
p <- p + geom_ribbon(aes(x = x, ymin = 0, ymax = y, group = Param, fill = Param), alpha = 0.3, position = position_stack())
p
```

further, how can I look in the code of functions coded the way geom_XXX are?
my traditional way gives the following, which is not very usefull:

```
> geom_ribbon
function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", position = "identity", 
    na.rm = FALSE, ...) 
GeomRibbon$new(mapping = mapping, data = data, stat = stat, position = position, 
    na.rm = na.rm, ...)
```

Thanks for your help
Regards
Pascal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just didn't map a variable to `y` in your `geom_ribbon` call. Adding `y = y` causes it to work for me. In general, `geom_ribbon` doesn't require a `y` aesthetic, but I believe it does in the case of stacking. I presume there's a well-thought out reasoning for why that is, but you never know...

Also, all the source code for **ggplot2** is on [github](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2).